# Node.js card content alignment

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

Hello i am writting story app, where user should see all stories. My cards have wrong text alignment. I have my own hbs helper and it is called truncate. I dont know if it works because text is not aligned. One of my helpers works, so i think that it is the problem with alignment.
[This is an image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDjF1.png)

```
        <div class="card-content center-align">
          <h5>{{title}}</h5>
          <p class="story-text">{{truncate body}}</p>
          <br>
          <div class="chip">
            <img src="{{user.image}}">
            {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
          </div>
        </div>
```

file with my helper

```
 module.exports = {
      truncate: function(str, len){
        if (str.length > len && str.length > 0) {
                var new_str = str + " ";
                new_str = str.substr(0, len);
                new_str = str.substr(0, new_str.lastIndexOf(" "));
                new_str = (new_str.length > 0) ? new_str : str.substr(0, len);
                return new_str + '...';
            }
            return str;
      },
formatDate: function(date, format){
    return moment(date).format(format);
  }
    }
```

app.js

```
const {
  truncate,
 formatDate
} = require('./helpers/hbs');

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  helpers: {
    truncate: truncate,
    formatDate:formatDate
  },
  defaultLayout:'main'
}));
```

Comment: This is a problem best solved by CSS, not server side template helpers.

Comment: how can i solve that problem with css?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/